# Android MotionEvent getY returns when finger moves out of view

Tags: android, keyboard, touch, gesture

I am making a keyboard app. I want to receive the touch coordinates  when the user starts swiping inside the keyboard and goes outside the keyboard view.

I'm overriding the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)` as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    int action = me.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

        Log.d("testing", "touchY = " + me.getY());

        return true;
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}
```

But once the user goes out of the `KeyboardView`, `me.getY()` keeps returning zero even when the user  slides his finger vertically. Interestingly `me.getX()` gives the correct value even when finger moves out of the `KeyboardView`

My guess is it has something to do with **Permissions** or `Window LayoutParams` flags or similar.

Comment: motionEvent is not for specific view but it consider the whole screen

Comment: @GovindRathod I'm afraid it is. This is a keyboard app so I won't receive touches that have occurred outside the `KeyboardView`

Comment: KeyboardView only returns coordinates within its own boundaries (same with  getRawX()). If the pointer is outside the boundaries it returns the closest coordinates inside KeyboardView. An invisible view the size of the whole screen needs to be created so that it can capture MotionEvents and and pass on the appropriate ones to KeyboardView